# how to set margin-left on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I make a slider in jquery using `animate` function and `margin-left`.

please check my jquery code
https://jsfiddle.net/uvsb6asa/10/

```
 function addToMarginLeft(elem, pixels) {
    var ml = parseFloat(elem.css('margin-left'));
    elem.animate({
    'margin-left': (ml + pixels) + 'px'
    },1000)

  }
```

I want to make same functionality in angular 4 . I am able to add fade in and fade out animation on button click . but how I will set margin-left or sliding effect from `left to right` in button click

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-animation-ztr63u?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
animations: [trigger("fade", [
  state("void", style({ opacity: 0 })),
  transition("void <=> *", [animate("0.5s ease-in-out")])
  ])]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to play with "transform" instead of "opacity"

```
animations: [trigger("move", [
 state("void", style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
 transition("void => *", [animate("0.5s ease-in-out")])
])]
```

I think this code is similar to your jquery effect

```
animations: [trigger("move", [
  transition(':enter', [
    animate(500, style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate(500, style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
  ])
])]
```

Comment: it not look ok when user press `previous button`

Comment: `next` button click look good button  see `jquery` url and previous button functionality

Comment: @naveen then you need to manipulate with animation states (see [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-animation-tpvt9c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

Comment: @llia can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255873/how-to-show-two-image-one-time-in-angular-and-slide-only-one-at-time